# What do the bar colors mean, during gym fight?

Tags: pokemon-go

In Pokémon Go fights, a bar shows your remaining HP.
If I understand correctly, the level of remaining HP is the **length** of the bar.
But in addition, this bar has **colors**:

- Green
- Orange
- Red

[image: Pokemon Go gym fight color bars]

**QUESTION:** What is the meaning of each color?
For instance, if Venonat has its bar 10% red and 5% orange (as seen above), what does it actually mean?

Answer (score 5):

From my experience with the game, I have theorized this from the colors:

### Green

Health is excellent or near full.

### Yellow

Health is somewhere around the middle of the bar.

### Orange

Can show up at any time during a fight, it indicates how much health a Pokemon is about to lose from an attack.

### Red

Health is critically low, and the Pokemon may faint soon.

I'll have to look around and see if there's a concrete source backing this up, but this has been my experience with gyms and the health bar thus far.

Comment: This is the same in each pokemon game, so what you're saying is correct. This is how pokemon fights go.

Comment: In my experience it seems like the orange health is damage you've dealt client side that hasn't been recognized by the server yet. When the server updates it takes away the orange chunk

Comment: the orange isn't how much hp it's going to lose from an attack, it's the health that has been lost in the previous combo.

Answer (score 1):

The HP bar has three colours depending on how much health a Pokémon has, red for low, yellow for medium and green for high. I do not know at exactly what percentages these change.

A portion of the bar is also coloured orange. This is the amount of damage dealt during the current turn of attacks. On a 1v1 match, it may seem irrelevant, but when you have 2v1 or more, this shows you how much damage is being dealt overall to the defending Pokémon.

Comment: Ack I didn't realize yellow was a thing, I'm adding that into my answer!